# Cucumber - Cypress Istanbul integration

Tags: reactjs, cucumber, cypress, istanbul

I have made a project with React, Cypress, Cucumber and Cypress Image Snapshot in order to test front-end testing. All works well and now I would like to get some code coverage for the executed cucumber tests.

I have tried to set it up as suggested here (https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage), but had no luck.

I have tried this solution (https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/346#issuecomment-365220178) as well, but with the same result.

The tests end in a success, but the code coverage shows `Unknown% 0/0` for   Statements, Branches, Functions and Lines.

---

My current setup:

`support/index.js`

```
import '@cypress/code-coverage/support'
import './commands'
```

`plugins/index.js`

```
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default;
const {
  addMatchImageSnapshotPlugin,
} = require('cypress-image-snapshot/plugin');

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  addMatchImageSnapshotPlugin(on, config);
  on('task', require('@cypress/code-coverage/task'))
  on('file:preprocessor', cucumber());
};
```

Comment: You already know you are testing the coverage of the application you are testing right? The application you are testing should be instrumented inorder cypress code-coverage to work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not mentioned anything about instrumenting the application, the web application you are testing should be instrumented in order code-coverage to work.

More about instrumenting the application

https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage#instrument-your-application

Answer (score 0):

Code coverage requires your code to be instrumented first. In React application, the simplest way to instrument your code is by using [@cypress/instrument-cra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cypress/instrument-cra). Just add this instrumentation in your start script in package.json

```
"start": "react-scripts -r @cypress/instrument-cra start"
```

This will instrument your code every time you will start your application and generate a .nyc-output folder at the root of your application which will contain all instrumented code.
You can verify whether your code is instrumented or not by checking the window coverage object.

**Complete Setup:**

package.json

```
"start": "react-scripts -r @cypress/instrument-cra start"

::::

"nyc": {
"extends": "@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript",
"all": true,
"report-dir": "coverage",
"reporter": [
  "text",
  "json",
  "lcov",
  "html"
],
"include": [
  "src/**/*.js"
],
"exclude": [
  "**/*.test.js",
  "**/test.js",
  "src/**/*.test.js",
  "src/**/**/*.test.js"
]
```

}

plugins/index.js

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
require('@cypress/code-coverage/task')(on, config);
return config;
```

support/index.js

```
import '@cypress/code-coverage/support';
```